# Smart extended test fails on same LBA every time. Is my drive really dying?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, hard-drive-failure

I ran a smart extended test on my old laptop's hard disk, and got a read error. I ran it again, and it got the same LBA of the error. Does this mean the disk is really dying, or just that there is a bad block or two? Additionally, when I look at the individual smart attributes, they are well over the threshold, even though the drive is pretty old.

Based on this, is the hard drive actually going bad? Or is smart just acting weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LBA is just another name for sector.  Based solely on the information we know you have 1 bad sector.  You need to find the total number of bad sectors in order to know what condition the hard drive is in.

1 bad sector is hardly the end of the world, but more will following over the coming years.  The total number and rate at which the occur tells you more about the drives overall health.

You should

1. Make sure your backup is in good working order
2. Start putting money away so in 6 months, a year, or whenever it fails you can replace it.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm running `badblocks` on the drive now, so far it's found 7 errors and is mostly done, so there are probably about 10 total bad blocks, which doesn't sound too bad to me. I use this PC as a low-powered web server and minecraft server, if it's on 24/7 with not too many reads and writes how long do you think it will last before it dies completely?

Comment: If you have 10 bad sectors, you probably have at least a year, maybe more.  I would re-scan once a month, and check for new bad blocks.  If it less than 2 several months, normal aging.  If it was 2,3,2,2,1,2, and 99 well obviously the massive jump means the end is near.